# Accessing a property of a Javascript object with bracket notation

Tags: javascript

I want to access the property values of...

```
var $o = {a:2, b:{c:6}};
```

...via $o[*index*] notation.

I'm using the newest Firebug console (I don't know whether it's using ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode), but when I use $o[0], $o[0].a or $o['0'], I get undefined and TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "index" should be one of the property names you've actually got, if you expect it to work.  In particular, numeric indexes aren't really special in any way, and you can't use array-indexing semantics to extract properties from a plain object. That is, you cannot get to the property values of an object by numeric index unless the name of the properties are already numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Objects do not have indexes, only properties.

Arrays have indexes, but can also have properties as they are a subclass of Object.

Since you have an object, you need to do `$o["a"]`.

Answer (score 0):

`$o` is object, you can operate with it as only associative array:

```
$o['a']
```

Or simple as object:

```
$o.a
```

You can't operate with object as with numeric array.

Comment: Please do not use terms such as 'associative array' when referring to javscript - it creates confusion as this really isn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JSON standard, one could have an object property with brackets surround a string similar to associative array. However, in javascript, this is not valid: var b = {Name[first]: "John"};

for example, following code is valid:

```js
var jstr = '{"Name[first]": "John"}';
var person = JSON.parse(jstr);
console.log(person);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person["Name[first]"];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<p id="demo">Display the result here.</p>
```